# How to create a Duplicate Node from a Node in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am copying part of my Main Neo4j Graph(mainDB) into another Graph (dupDB), while doing so how can I create a Node in dupDB that has similar properties as one in mainDB.

I would do

```
Node main = mainDB.getNodeByID(477);
Node dup = dupDB.createNode();
```

Now I have to copy each property in main to dup manually, is there any one-line method to do this?

Comment: Are you just duplicating the node and the properties or even its relationships, e.g. a subgraph? Generally, do the copying by looping over the props, with Cypher you could use one map as a parameter to insert it, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-create.html#create-create-single-node-from-map

Comment: Only properties. Anyway I had copied them manually, was just curious if there was a direct method.

Comment: in case you want just to copy the whole db, you can try simply to copy and rename the files in the `data` folder on the disk

Answer (score 9):

You can create a duplicate with a map in Neo4j 2.1 (not sure of earlier)

```
MATCH (n:Node {name: 'abc'}) 
WITH n AS map 
CREATE (copy:Node) 
SET copy=map
RETURN copy
```

If you have a uniqueness constraint on any of the properties it will fail though with the message...

> *Node  already exists with label XX and property "property"=[value]*

You can avoid that by supplying a new value for the property with the uniqueness constraint, creating the new node and copying the other non-unique property values from the original node.

```
MATCH (n:Node {name: 'abc'}) 
WITH n as map 
CREATE (copy:Node {name: 'def'}) 
SET copy.property1 = map.property1
, copy.property2 = map.property2
RETURN copy
```

Comment: Note that if you have a lot of properties and just want to change a couple, it is possible to use the copy=map thing and just overwrite what you like with set.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this existed a year ago. However this might solve the problem today.

The Neo4j shell has a dump command: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements

```
dump START n=node({self}) MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) return n,r,m;
```

You could then take the output of this and send it to another database to create those nodes, properties and all.

Answer (score 0):

These days, there are functions for cloning nodes in the APOC library, see [Neo4j Docs - Clone nodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/graph-refactoring/clone-nodes/) for example.

One example from the docs:

```
MATCH (f:Foo{name:'Foo'}),(b:Bar{name:'Bar'})
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodes([f,b])
YIELD input, output, error
RETURN *
```

You can also clone nodes with relationships, clone nodes while skipping properties, etc.